# Passing value through the ng-include tag

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angular js. I have requirement that I will get values for the database to user.html. In this page (user.html)  I need to call details.html so I am using the ng-include tag to call the details.html. While calling  I need to pass some values to details.html, this value will be dynamic, this dynamic value I need to pass details.html.

Example:

```
RouteManager.js:

.when( '/mydetails',
{
  templateUrl : "./client/assets/views/user.html",
  controller  : "MyDetailsController"
 })

user.html:

<div ng-include="'client/assets/views/details.html'" {{here i need to pass two parameters }}></div>

details.html:

<h1>{{need to display that two parameters}}</h1>
```

Note: For details.html there is not controller. We need to do without controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code -

```
<div ng-include="'client/assets/views/details.html'" ng-init="myItem = myItemValue"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use onload:

```
<div ng-include="'myComponent.html'"
     ng-controller="myComponentController"
     onload="myItem = myItemValue">
</div>
```

This is the recommended way in the documentation.

Comment: instead of onload, use "ng-init"